# Removing lines with past dates from a text file

Tags: powershell

I have a text file called HelplineSpecialRoster.txt that looks like this

```
01/01/2019,6AM,0400012345,Kurt,kurt@outlook.com
02/01/2019,6AM,0412345676,Bill,bill@outlook.com
03/01/2019,6AM,0400012345,Sam,Sam@outlook.com
04/01/2019,6AM,0412345676,Barry,barry@outlook.com
05/01/2019,6AM,0400012345,Kurt,kurt@outlook.com
```

I'm in Australia so the dates are day/month/year.

I have some code that creates a listbox that displays the lines from the text file, but I want to edit the text file before it is displayed to only show older dates. A helpful person gave me this code and it worked once but now it stopped working for some reason. When I delete the whole text file and recreated it it started working again but only once.

If there is a future shift in the file say

```
05/02/2019,6AM,0400012345,Kurt,kurt@outlook.com
```

and todays date being 29/01/2019 it works to delete the older shifts. If there is only old shifts in the file as above, it doesn't delete them. When I add a date that is in the future, then it works to delete the older ones and only keep the future one.

```
$SpecialRosterPath = "C:\Helpline Dialer\HelplineSpecialRoster.txt"
$CurrentDate2 = (Get-Date).Date  # to have a datetime starting today at 00:00:00

Function DeleteOlderShifts {
    $CurrentAndFutureShifts = Get-Content $SpecialRosterPath | Where-Object {
        $_ -match "^(?<day>\d{2})\/(?<mon>\d{2})\/(?<year>\d{4})" -and
        (Get-Date -Year $Matches.year -Month $Matches.mon -Day $Matches.day) -ge $CurrentDate2
    }
    $CurrentAndFutureShifts
    $CurrentAndFutureShifts | Set-Content $SpecialRosterPath
}

DeleteOlderShifts;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try `Import-Csv -UseCulture` instead of `Get-Content`. Then, comparing date in the 1st column could become easier.

Comment: While I'd say that the chosen approach does have room for improvement it should work in principle (and apparently has in the past). If re-creating the input file solves the problem then the problem is likely with the input file/data, not the code itself. Perhaps an encoding issue. However, we cannot analyze this without access to a working and a non-working sample input file.

Comment: I have some more information. if there is a future shift in the file say `05/02/2019,6AM,0400012345,Kurt,kurt@outlook.com` and todays date being 29/01/2019 it works to delete the older shifts. If there is only old shifts in the file as above, it doesn't delete them. when I add a date that is in the future, then it works to delete the older ones and only keep the future one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there are only older dates in your input file the result in `$CurrentAndFutureShifts` will be empty. Empty values in a pipeline are skipped over, meaning that nothing is written to the output file, so the output file remains unchanged.

You can avoid this issue by passing the variable to the parameter `-Value`. Change

```
$CurrentAndFutureShifts | Set-Content $SpecialRosterPath
```

into

```
Set-Content -Value $CurrentAndFutureShifts -Path $SpecialRosterPath
```

Comment: This is the answer for me, Thankyou. Took me a while to figure out what was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a text file, use a CSV file with headers. This is essentially just a text file saved with a .csv file extension that includes headers for each column:

Note I have added an additional row at the bottom with a date older than today's to prove testing.

HelpineSpecialRoster.csv content:

```
Date,Time,Number,Name,Email
01/01/2019,6AM,400012345,Kurt,kurt@outlook.com
02/01/2019,6AM,412345676,Bill,bill@outlook.com
03/01/2019,6AM,400012345,Sam,Sam@outlook.com
04/01/2019,6AM,412345676,Barry,barry@outlook.com
05/01/2019,6AM,400012345,Kurt,kurt@outlook.com
01/02/2019,6AM,400012345,Dan,dan@outlook.com
```

Set the path of the CSV:

```
$csvPath = "C:\HelpineSpecialRoster.csv"
```

Import CSV from file:

```
$csvData = Import-CSV $csvPath
```

Get todays date @ 00:00

```
$date = (Get-Date).Date
```

Filter csv data to show rows where the date is older than today's date:

```
$csvData = $csvData | ? { (Get-Date $date) -lt (Get-Date $_.Date) }
```

Export the CSV data back over the original CSV:

```
$csvData | Export-CSV $csvPath -Force
```

Comment: Thanks I will try that next,  I have some more information. if there is a future shift in the file say `05/02/2019,6AM,0400012345,Kurt,kurt@outlook.com` and todays date being 29/01/2019 it works to delete the older shifts. If there is only old shifts in the file as in my question above, it doesn't delete them for some reason. When I add a date that is in the future, then it works to delete the older ones and only keep the future one.

Comment: `Import-Csv` can be used even without headers in the file itself: `Import-Csv input.csv -Header Date,Time,Number,Name,Email`.

Comment: I'd personally stray away from the approach in your example. This will mean adjusting the code that feeds this file into your drop down menu. Totally worth it in my opinion.